# Alert Popup does not work when placed under an If condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a bound script with a google sheet I am working on. When I put in the following function on its own, it will work just fine:

```
function notify() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

However, when I place it under an If condition, it either does not work or a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" occurs. An example of what I have tried looks like this:

```
function onEdit() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sht2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  unhideSheets(ss,sht2);
  notify(ss,sht2);
}

function notify(ss,sht2){
  const r = sht2.getRange("J2:J");
  if(r.getValue == "True"){
    return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

I have tried about every suggestion that I could find online from people who were looking for a similar solution.
What I would like to happen, is when a cell in "sheet2" column 10 or J appears as "True", the alert popup will appear on the Spreadsheet.
Cells in column J appear as "True" using a formula that compares when two different cells have the same value. Both of those cells are also in "sheet2". I have tried if statements using column J, but also directly comparing the two cells. Again this results with either the script running and nothing occurring or a TypeError when running the script. Note: the unhideSheets found under the onEdit function is a different function that works perfectly.

I am very new to script and could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the error line in your showing script?

Comment: The range J2:J contains many cells which might have "True" and other values as well. How should we combine them in your logic? If the only J2 is important, then try `if(sht2.getRange("J2").getValue() == "True")` ...

Comment: The error line has been showing up in the const r line of the notify function. It seems to happen whenever I am trying to pull info from the onEdit function. I'm just confused because my unHideSheets function(which is not shown) works just fine. Would it help to have a copy of the spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am unable to assist you further. I suggest that you share your spreadsheet, ensure that your spreadsheet, ensure that your script reflects the data in your spreadsheet, and explain how your spreadsheet is used and the kind of edit that you expect to trigger the function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get all of my functions to work. This is the alert popup function I used:

```
function notify() {
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sht22 = ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var j2 = sht22.getRange('J2');
  if(j2.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j3 = sht22.getRange('J3');
  if(j3.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j4 = sht22.getRange('J4');
  if(j4.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j5 = sht22.getRange('J5');
  if(j5.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j6 = sht22.getRange('J6');
  if(j6.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j7 = sht22.getRange('J7');
  if(j7.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j8 = sht22.getRange('J8');
  if(j8.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j9 = sht22.getRange('J9');
  if(j9.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j10 = sht22.getRange('J10');
  if(j10.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are ready for the next level!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
  var j11 = sht22.getRange('J11');
  if(j11.getValue() == 'True') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations ","You are a year 1 expert!", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

I then went to triggers, clicked "+ add trigger," and filled in these parameters:
Choose which function to run: notify,
Choose which deployment should run: Head,
Select event source: Spreadsheet,
Select event type: On Change.

This allowed the alert popup to appear when the specific cell in Sheet2 displayed "true." I moved all of my unhideSheets function under the onEdit function I had before and that still works as it should. Thanks everyone for your patience.